# How to fix encoding

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhsp0.png)I am using the code snippet below, but the accent is being printed the wrong way. I already configured **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** for **-Dfile.encoding = UTF-8** and in the eclipse IDE the text file enconding is for UTF-8, but the problem continues. If possible I would like the help of the community to solve this problem.

```
Map<String, String> mapStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();

final String deviceInformation = String.format(
        "\nID: %1$s \nIP: %2$s \nPlataforma: %3$s \nVersão Firmware: %4$s "
                + "\nData Firmware: %5$s \nData Aplicativo: %6$s \nGMT: %7$s \nEmergência: %8$s \nLeitoras Habilitadas:"
                + " %9$s",
        deviceId, deviceIP, platform, versionFirmware, lastFirmwareUpdate, lastConfUpdate, gmt, emergency,
        readerBlock);               

    mapStatus.put("Informações do Dispositivo ", deviceInformation);
    deviceStatus.setStatus(mapStatus);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvYlq.png)

Comment: Replace `ã` with u-escaped `\u00E3`. If then the letter is correct, the java comipiler uses an other encoding than the editor.

Comment: How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the `<head>` section of your `html`.